# Thermal Expansion in Isotropic Objects

Tags: thermodynamics

Are the following three formulae derived for thermal expansion of isotropic objects valid for gases?

d*l* = L(1+$\alpha$$\Delta$T)
d*A* = A(1+$\beta$$\Delta$T)
d*V* = V(1+$\gamma$$\Delta$T)

My professor told me that they are not, but I just saw a problem involving some expansion of an ideal gas whose solution involved using the third formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how small the change in temperature is. Even the formula you wrote are usually valid for small $\Delta T$.

Technically we can write the same formula for a gas, using the ideal gas equation of state $PV=nRT$ under isobaric conditions ($P=$const) for example:
$$V=\frac{nR}{P}T \to \Delta V=\frac{nR}{P}\Delta T=V\frac{\Delta T}{T}$$

So we have $\alpha=\frac{1}{T}$. But as you see, the isobaric expansion coefficient $\alpha$ is sensitive to $T$, while for most solids, it is can be assumed to be constant over a range of temperatures.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!